# Time complexity of finding median of two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, median

I have followed median compare algorithm to find median of two sorted arrays and implemented in java. As per algorithm time complexity is O(lgn) but since it involves creating subarrays(method createSubArr) then I think as per my code it's O(n). Below is code implemented by me.

```
class Median
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = {1,12,15,26,38,40};
        int[] b = {2,13,17,30,45,50};
        System.out.println(getMedian(a,b,6));
    }

    private static int median(int[] a, int n){
        if(n % 2 == 0) return (a[n/2] + a[(n/2)-1])/2;
        else return a[n/2];
    }
    private static void show(int[] a) {
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    private static int[] createSubArr(int[] a, int start){
        int[] sub = new int[a.length-start];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length-start;i++) sub[i] = a[start+i];
        return sub;
    }
    private static int getMedian(int[] a, int[] b,int n){
        int m1,m2;
        int start=-1;
        int ans = -1;
        if(n<=0) return -1;
        if(n==1) return (a[0] + b[0])/2;
        if(n==2) return (Math.max(a[0],b[0])  + Math.min(a[1],b[1]) )/2;
        m1=median(a,n);
        m2=median(b,n);
        if(m1 < m2) {
            if(n%2==0){
                start = (n/2)-1;
                a = createSubArr(a,start);
            }
            else {
                start = (n/2);
                a = createSubArr(a,(n/2));
            }
        }else{
            if(n%2==0){
                start = (n/2)-1;
                b = createSubArr(b,start);
            }
            else {
                start = (n/2);
                b = createSubArr(b,start);
            }
        }
        return getMedian(a,b,n-start);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Create an abstraction for a sub array instead of copying from one to the other.

Comment: can you please explain more? Thanks

Comment: it will be (max(1,3) + min(2,4))/2 = (3+2)/2 which is same as if array was [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two extra parameters to `getMedian`: the start indices of `a` and `b`, then there is no need to copy data.

Besides, instead of the snippet:

```
if (n%2 == 0) {
    x = n/2 - 1;
} else {
    x = n/2;
}
```

you can simply use `(n-1)/2;`

You would need to adapt the following two methods to get a `O(lg n)` algorithm (not tested):

```
private static int median(int[] a, int a0, int n){
    if(n % 2 == 0) return (a[a0 + n/2] + a[a0 + (n/2)-1])/2;
    else return a[a0 + n/2];
}

private static int getMedian(int[] a, int a0, int[] b, int b0,int n){
    int m1,m2;
    int start=-1;
    int ans = -1;
    if(n<=0) return -1;
    if(n==1) return (a[a0] + b[b0])/2;
    if(n==2) return (Math.max(a[a0],b[b0])  + Math.min(a[a0+1],b[b0+1]) )/2;
    m1=median(a, a0,n);
    m2=median(b, b0,n);
    if(m1 < m2) {
        return getMedian(a, (n-1)/2, b, b0, n - (n-1)/2);
    } else {
        return getMedian(a, a0, b, (n-1)/2, n - (n-1)/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion let me test this. Yes the definition was mentioned as if length is even then it's mean of two middle elements and if it's odd then it's middle element.

Comment: Median of a set is usually defined as the middle element when set size is odd or the mean of middle elements when its even. Never heard of "pick any element" before! Source: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StatisticalMedian.html

Comment: Interesting @polvoazul! It has been almost 7 years, I have no idea how I came up with that definition :) I'll just remove the note because it seems the other definition is indeed universally accepted.

Comment: No problem! These things happen sometimes 